# Magento 2 - Can't log in to backend after changing cookie domain

Tags: magento2, session, cookie, domain, cookie-domain

My magento project is running on a subdomain `redesign.company.de`.

I have changed the cookie domain from empty to `.redesign.company.de`, because I often had issues where my site was loading forever and nothing happend until I delete all magento cookies.

Then I deleted all browser cookies and flushed the magento cache.

#### Problem:

If I try to login to the backend (admin) then the login form just reloads without any error showing.

My only option is to override the value from the database.

But how should I set the cookie domain correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the cookie domain as `www.company.de` (if you have a prod env on that domain) and `redesign.company.de` on your staging/ test environment.

Comment: Does not work, now I can't login to frontend and if I try to load the backend login form I get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: check my update pls, i initially made an assumption which might be wrong. i updated my answer.

Comment: It works with `redesign.company.de` or with empty cookie domain, but the cookie issue persists. Sometimes if I flush the cache or work with grunt then it just loads forever, until I delete all cookies. But maybe this is not related to the cookie domain.

Comment: yeah, it doesn't seem to be related to this tbh. as an explanation to my answer, Magento will add the leading dot in the cookie domain you see in your browser `Application -> Cookies` window, this is why don't need to add it. as for the other problem, may I suggest  you open a separate question? the login problem as described by you and related to cookies is solved now